# Rendering Page using Partials using Mustache.js

Tags: mustache

I Actualy made an html page Called Rendr.html

and try this code-----

In script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tmpl = "{{>rendr}} {{>inc/header}} {{>../header}}",
data = {},
partials = {
    header : "<h2>First</h2>",
    'inc/header' : "<h1>rendr</h1>",
    '../header' : "<h4>whatever</h4>",
    'rendr' :"rendr.html"
},
html = Mustache.render(tmpl, data, partials);

document.write(html);
</script>
```

But it simply prints render.html not rendering to that page.

Comment: Are you trying to render the contents of `rendr.html` as a partial?